# How do I get a list of startup programs from the Vista command prompt?

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, boot, malware-removal

On a badly malware infested computer without AV and other protection, the bad guys often have to be removed by hand. The first step to removing them is to identify them. So, how does one get a list of startup programs from the Vista command prompt, which would be faster than using GUI tools, since the system can get really sluggish due to the malware eating up CPU cycles and doing other naughty stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Vista command prompt (no elevation required) type:

```
wmic startup list full | more
```

> **Windows Management Instrumentation
>   Command-line** (WMIC) uses the
>   power of Windows Management
>   Instrumentation (WMI) to enable
>   systems management from the command
>   line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a native solution but [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) by Sysinternals/Microsoft provides a console version along with the GUI version.

Answer (score 0):

The '[`autoruns`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)' tool from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) is quite good and light weight.
Allows you to quickly disable an autorun too.